# Gradle 'My Application' project refresh failed

Tags: android, ubuntu, solus

```
Gradle 'My Application' project refresh failed
        На устройстве не осталось свободного места
    Error:
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Друзья, кто сталкивался с подобной ошибкой? Отпишитесь пожалуйста.
Места полно! Это первый запуск, после переустановки системы с Ubuntu на Solus 3 Badgie, студия встала без проблем! Она есть в репозитарии данного дистрибутива.

Comment: покажите `more details`